# Query that returns the count of all distinct days between multiple start and end dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm going to simplify the basis for asking the question. I have two tables in the ORACLE database: one called 'tb_vehicle' (id_vehicle, model, ...) and another table 'tb_trip' (id_vehicle, dt_start, dt_end, ...).

I am not able to carry out a query that returns the number of days that each vehicle was on the trip, excluding the repeated days (what do you mean? in the same day a vehicle can leave 1, 2, 3, ... times, however, I just need to know that the vehicle left on the day and not the number of times it left [I already made this query for another chart and it was very quiet]).

Example:

tb_vehicle

| id_vehicle | model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Chevrolet Cruze |
| 2 | Chevrolet Sonic |

tb_trip

| id_vehicle | dt_start | dt_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06-05-2023 | 06-05-2023 |
| 1 | 06-05-2023 | 06-05-2023 |
| 1 | 06-05-2023 | 06-08-2023 |
| 2 | 06-05-2023 | 06-06-2023 |

OBS: I am ignoring in this example the hours and minutes

intended result:

| id_vehicle | model | qtd_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chevrolet Cruze | 4 |
| 2 | Chevrolet Sonic | 2 |

I was able to count the individual statistics for each vehicle using PL/SQL. But I need to perform this query only with SQL.

The system is developed at APEX.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: Thank you. Does your tb_trip table have an ID column?

Comment: Yes, I just simplified the example. There are many other fields in each of these tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  tb_vehicle (id_vehicle, model) as
  3    (select 1, 'Chevrolet Cruze' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Chevrolet Sonic' from dual
  5    ),
  6  tb_trip (id_vehicle, dt_start, dt_end) as
  7    (select 1, date '2023-06-05', date '2023-06-05' from dual union all
  8     select 1, date '2023-06-05', date '2023-06-05' from dual union all
  9     select 1, date '2023-06-05', date '2023-06-08' from dual union all
 10     select 2, date '2023-06-05', date '2023-06-06' from dual
 11    ),
```

Query begins here; `temp` CTE lists all dates between start and end date; the final query calculates distinct dates per vehicle (along with join to `tb_vehicle` table):

```
 12  temp as
 13    (select t.id_vehicle, t.dt_start + column_value - 1 datum
 14     from tb_trip t cross join
 15       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 16                           connect by level <= dt_end - dt_start + 1
 17                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 18    )
 19  select a.id_vehicle, m.model, count(distinct a.datum) qtd_Days
 20  from temp a join tb_vehicle m on m.id_vehicle = a.id_vehicle
 21  group by a.id_Vehicle, m.model
 22  order by a.id_Vehicle;

ID_VEHICLE MODEL             QTD_DAYS
---------- --------------- ----------
         1 Chevrolet Cruze          4
         2 Chevrolet Sonic          2

SQL>
```

Comment: This is a great solution. It took me a moment to understand, though, because Oracle is cheating here a little bit allowing `CROSS JOIN` when it's really a lateral cross join (`CROSS APPLY`), because you are referencing the first table's row in the join. A good idea to create the single days from the ranges first. Much better than what I had in mind :-)

Comment: I understood. thank you very much for answering. I will try to apply based on your answer

Comment: Apparently, it worked. Tomorrow I will dedicate more time to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Littlefoot's idea with a slightly different query. I am using a standard recursive CTE to generate the single days from the rows first. Then I count the distinct days per vehicle. At last I join this result to the vehicle table. You may find this query a tad easier to understand.

```
with single_days(id_vehicle, dt, dt_end) as
(
  select id_vehicle, dt_start, dt_end from tb_trip
  union all
  select id_vehicle, dt + 1, dt_end from single_days where dt < dt_end
)
, counted_days as
(
  select id_vehicle, count(distinct dt) as days
  from single_days
  group by id_vehicle
)
select *
from tb_vehicle v
join counted_days c using (id_vehicle);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/paJKama3

Comment: Really, it was easier to understand. Thank you very much. Despite Littlefoot's answer having a different approach, I was also able to understand his solution. I just have to thank everyone for their responses.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a list of all the days and then finding the distinct days is simple to code but if you have large ranges then it will become costly.

Instead you can merge the ranges (by `UNPIVOT`ing the dates and then using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to merge the overlaps) and then using arithmetic to calculate the size of the range and aggregating for each vehicle:

```sql
SELECT v.id_vehicle,
       MAX(v.model) AS model,
       SUM(t.dt_end - t.dt_start + 1) AS qtd_days
FROM   tb_trip
       UNPIVOT (
         dt FOR type IN (dt_start AS 1, dt_end AS -1)
       )
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY id_vehicle
         ORDER BY dt, type DESC
         MEASURES
           FIRST(dt) AS dt_start,
           LAST(dt)  AS dt_end
         PATTERN ( overlaps+ range_end )
         DEFINE
           overlaps  AS SUM(type) > 0,
           range_end AS SUM(type) = 0
       ) t
       INNER JOIN tb_vehicle v
       ON (t.id_vehicle = v.id_vehicle)
GROUP BY v.id_vehicle
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_vehicle (id_vehicle, model) AS
SELECT 1, 'Chevrolet Cruze' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Chevrolet Sonic' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'DeLorean' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tb_trip (id_vehicle, dt_start, dt_end) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-05', DATE '2023-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-05', DATE '2023-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-06-05', DATE '2023-06-08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-06-05', DATE '2023-06-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '1885-01-01', DATE '9999-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID_VEHICLE | MODEL | QTD_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chevrolet Cruze | 4 |
| 2 | Chevrolet Sonic | 2 |
| 3 | DeLorean | 2963942 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/srUiviCg)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below can meet your need :

```
select v.id
       ,v.model
       ,sum(case when DT_END<>DT_START then DT_END - DT_START + 1 else 0 end) qtd_days
from tb_trip t,
    tb_vehicle v
where t.id_vehicle = v.id
group by v.id ,v.model 
order by v.id
```

Comment: This is only valid for the OP's sample data when the trips are either same-day or spanning the entire range. If the data had the dates 2023-06-05 to 2023-06-06 and then, for the same vehicle, from 2023-06-06 to 2023-06-08 then you would give a total of 2+3 = 5 days when it is only 4 days and you have double-counted 2023-06-06.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version using MATCH_RECOGNIZE

```
with tb_trip(id_vehicle, dt_start, dt_end) as (
    select 1, to_date('06-05-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), to_date('06-05-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual union all
    select 1, to_date('06-05-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), to_date('06-05-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual union all
    select 1, to_date('06-05-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), to_date('06-08-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual union all
    select 2, to_date('06-05-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), to_date('06-06-2023', 'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual -- union all
),
tb_vehicle(id_vehicle, model) as (
    select 1, 'Chevrolet Cruze' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Chevrolet Sonic' from dual
)
select d.id_vehicle, v.model, sum(dt_end - dt_start +1) as days
from (
    select * from tb_trip
    match_recognize (
        partition by id_vehicle
        order by dt_start, dt_end
        measures first(dt_start) as dt_start, max(dt_end) as dt_end
        pattern( overlaps* strt )
        define
            overlaps as dt_end >= dt_start
    )
) d
join tb_vehicle v on v.id_vehicle = d.id_vehicle
group by d.id_vehicle, v.model
;
```